# Another sequence of numbers

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

Here at Puzzling there are many sequences of numbers already. I come up with another one, that I haven't found so far.

```
     10
    1 10
   1 1 1 10
  11 1 1 10
1 11 10 1 1 10
```

What is the next line?

Comment: @dcfyj Why put you the same link as athin? athin is right. It's the same solving strategy, but IMHO not same question.

Comment: That's an automatic comment from when I flagged it as a possible duplicate. Just because you obfuscate the pattern behind a layer of encryption doesn't mean it's not the same question. On here binary may as well be decimal, pretty much every one knows it and can read it off-hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next line is

> 1 1 1 11 1 10 10 1 1 10

Because

> This is essentially a version of the [Look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) where begin with 2 (i.e, 2, 12, 1112, 3112, 132112, 1113122112, ...) but each line is the corresponding number with each digit translated to binary and arranged in a sequence.